# JLabel icon does not display with clojure and miglayout

Tags: clojure, icons, jlabel, miglayout

Still pretty green on clojure, java, layouts etc.
On a miglayout I have this line to insert an icon on Jlabel:

```
(JLabel. "" "C:\\MyPriject\Pictures\\TCM00.jpg")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
#<CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class javax.swing.JLabel (NO_SOURCE_FILE:901)>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry in the posted path a "\" is missing, but it is ok in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JLabel` has no constructor that takes two String arguments.

If you want just an icon (and no text), there is a constructor that takes one `Icon`. The class `ImageIcon` (which implements `Icon`) has a constructor that takes a filename String. So this should work:

```
(JLabel. (ImageIcon. "C:\\MyPriject\Pictures\\TCM00.jpg"))
```

See the javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html

Comment: Thanks Christian. Things look not as green now.